# Enable Flow Control on a VMware vSwitch

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi, vmware-vsphere

I can't figure out how to enable Flow Control on a VMware vSwitch. I've been talking with Equallogic and VMware, and they said we need it on for better performance. I can't find out how to enable it on the vSwitch, or is it on by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that is negotiated by the physical switch attached to the physical ports of the ESX host...[Here's a KB](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1004089) on ESX physical adapters. Hope it helps...